# Phoenix/Elixir Background workers

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I need to setup a background worker in Phoenix and communicate with it from a channel through Elixir send/receive.

1. Where should I put a module for the working in the Phoenix dir structure (`lib` perhaps?)
2. How do I Load/Reference the module from channels?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. I think it depends on count of these modules. If you have only one, you could put it to `lib` directly. If there are many workers modules, I'd prefer put them to `lib/workers` or even to `workers`. In the latter case you should list `workers` folder in `elixirc_paths` function inside `mix.exs`.
2. Nothing special. All modules placed inside folders mentioned in `elixirc_paths` will be loaded automatically.